# Newsletter signup at checkout - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, newsletter

Is it possible for customers to sign up to a newsletter at checkout natively? I know there are extension out there to add in this functionality but I just can't believe its not native as it seems like a basic thing to want

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you give more info?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this is only possible with extensions or by writing your own code. [Subscribe at checkout](https://marketplace.magento.com/mageside-module-subscribe-at-checkout.html) is an extension that a lot of people use.